# Right way to get involved in open source projects?

Tags: git, open-source, github

With the ease usage and good design of github, we, actually just two, in a small technical company (or a mid-sized animation studio) would like to get involved in an open source project: [partio](https://github.com/wdas/partio/). We forked it and started committed/pushed some stuff. It just started and nothing bad or good happened. Because benefiting from open source for such a long time, I would like to feed back something useful or meaningful. I am wondering what should or shouldn't I do to make our tiny efforts contributive, but not harmful?

And then, another further question: what should we take care of while involved in open source projects?

Some other questions I have checked:

- [What are the most important points when getting involved in an open source project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644202/what-are-the-most-important-points-when-getting-involved-in-an-open-source-projec)
- [How to get involved in an open source project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649/how-to-get-involved-in-an-open-source-project)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about feedback on an open source project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A technical point:
Please rebase your local work on top of the branch from the original repo (that you add as a remote), before pushing your own branch and making pull request to said original project.
That will ensure that your **[pull request](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/)** can be applied in a fast-forward manner, without any merge conflict. (See also [Cherrypicking versus Rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475435/workflow-for-managing-pull-requests-on-shared-repos-in-github))

The rest is mainly a question of **communication**, typically through a bug-tracker in order to identify the current bug to fix and the features to add.
On that front, the [GitHub pull request2.0](https://github.com/blog/712-pull-requests-2-0) is a good illustration of that communication topic.

> As of today, pull requests are living discussions about the code you want merged. They're our take on code review and represent a big part of our vision for collaborative development.

[image]

Comment: +1 on the communication part. Github/git is the tool only. Another important thing is that building merit requires you to solve things for the project, usually starting with simpler tasks. For project leaders, the opposite is true: You must make it possible for others to build merit by having a wide spectrum of problems of different skillset/difficulty.